# Create a new file using android

Tags: android

I'm using that code to create a new xml file . But i want to put it  in an other file after checking if it already exists.

```
        private void XmlSms() {

            File newxmlfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/SmsFile.xml");
            try
        {
        Log.v(BackupFragment.this.getClass().getName(), "create file:"+ newxmlfile.createNewFile());
        }       
        catch (IOException e)
            {
    Log.e("IOException", "exception in createNewFile() method");
    }
            FileOutputStream fileos = null;
            try 
            {
    fileos = new FileOutputStream(newxmlfile);
    }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
    Log.e("FileNotFoundException", "can't create FileOutputStream");


}
```

Comment: Where is the question ? what have you already tried (and what does not work) ?

Comment: With that code the xml file is created directly in the root. i want to create a new file (newfile for example) and then put the xml file (SmsFile) in it . 
So the path will be /newfile/SmsFile/

Comment: You mean you want to create a directory and put your file in it ?

Comment: This is exactly what i meant. I know that i can use mkdir() but i don't know how to change my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `mkdirs()` to create the "newFile" directory, **before** writing your xml file in it :

```
File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"newfile");
directory.mkdirs();
```

and now, you can create your xml file in this new directory :

```
File newxmlfile= new File(directory , "SmsFile.xml);
newxmlfile.createNewFile()
```